# Why does 20.04 options show up on my Ubuntu 18.04 GRUB menu?

Tags: grub2

I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, no upgrade to 20.04 yet. But all of a  sudden, the 20.04 options show up on my GRUB menu. How do I remove them from the menu?

[image: GRUB menu image]

Comment: Do you have some secondary mass storage attached to your system? What happens when you click on 20.04?

Comment: You are right, I did system update while my raspberry pi sb card plugin, it's installed Ubuntu 20.04 server. That's the reason why. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think it had some grub problem,

You need to update grub info by using below command in Ubuntu terminal.

```
sudo update-grub
```

- It's update your grub detail and remove unbootable options.

**Note:** Make sure you don't inserted **bootable usb drive**, When you run this command.

Comment: Thank you so much. Problem is fixed. It's my raspberry pi sd card. I forgot to unplug it while doing system update